# Scanning tunneling spectroscopy of graphene: Energy gap and momentum mismatch

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, graphene

In some early experiments on scanning tunneling spectroscopy (STS) of graphene the gap of $\pm60\,\mbox{meV}$ around zero bias voltage was found (see the figure from [Y. Zhang et al., Nature Phys. 4, 627 (2008)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.4315)):

[image]

This gap was attributed to emission of $60\,\mbox{meV}$ acoustic phonon required to change electron momentum from $\boldsymbol\Gamma$ (outside graphene) to $\pm\mathbf{K}$ (near one of the Dirac points inside graphene).

**Why the same feature is not observed in some later STS experiments?** For example, the perfect STS Landau level picture is seen in [D.L. Miller et al., Science 324, 924 (2009)](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/324/5929/924), without any gap around the zero bias voltage:

[image]